# Dump tables from database in mysql?

Tags: mysql

How can I dump each table in database in separate file with that table name?

Comment: Also have a look at http://www.dagondesign.com/articles/automatic-mysql-backup-script/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to check out the shell script suggested in the following article:

- [How do I dump all tables in a database into separate files?](http://crazytoon.com/2007/11/26/mysql-how-do-i-dump-all-tables-in-a-database-into-separate-files/)  by Sunny Walia

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
db=$1
if [ "$db" = "" ]; then
echo "Usage: $0 db_name"
exit 1
fi
mkdir $$
cd $$
clear
for table in `mysql $db -e 'show tables' | egrep -v 'Tables_in_' `; do
echo "Dumping $table"
mysqldump --opt -Q $db $table > $table.sql
done
if [ "$table" = "" ]; then
echo "No tables found in db: $db"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Linux command line to backup all tables in `YOURDATABASENAME` to separate files in a specific path:

You will have to replace `YOURDATABASENAME` and `YOURPATH` with appropriate values.

```
for I in $(mysql --database=YOURDATABASENAME -e 'show tables' -s --skip-column-names); do mysqldump YOURDATABASENAME $I | gzip > "/YOURPATH/YOURDATABASENAME/$I.sql.gz"; done
```

I use this as a scheduled cron job to backup all tables daily.

NOTE: if you are using this from a Linux command line, you will have to have to add a user with global privileges to the database for `YOURUSERNAME@localhost` with no password. Otherwise, you will have to add user and password options to the script as follows, but this will require a password for each table!

```
 for I in $(mysql -u MYSQLUSERNAME -p --database=YOURDATABASENAME -e 'show tables' -s --skip-column-names); do mysqldump -u MYSQLUSERNAME -p YOURDATABASENAME $I | gzip > "/YOURPATH/YOURDATABASENAME/$I.sql.gz"; done
```